# Handle users with MySQL users or table w/ encrypted password?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am preparing a web application that runs only on local network for a small business.
I am using MYSQL and writing the front-end with PHP.

I am not sure on how to best handle users. I have roughly 20 different people accessing the app, and at least 3 different groups with different privileges.
So far I have created users and passwords in MYSQL directly, with a users table that stores personal info (name, last name, email and login info) but NOT the password.

My thought is that this way I can add a layer of security by restricting the users privileges on MYSQL (e.g. avoid that somebody access a page and calls a DELETE query).

I am worried, however, because this approach forces me to keep the password stored at all times (while using the app) in $_SESSION (because I need to connect to DB almost in every page).

Is this approach acceptable?

Comment: Why would that cause you to keep the password in SESSION? do you mistakenly use the users app account to connect to the database?

Comment: On most servers, PHP's session files are stored in plain text in a folder accessible by anyone with access to the server. That makes storing user passwords in the session a pretty big security risk. Besides that, I'm personally of the opinion "if I'm not allowed to delete a record, don't show me a delete button" which means the *application* needs to know what I'm allowed to do so it can choose to hide the button, rather than trying it and finding out later that the database wouldn't let me.

Comment: @BoredGeek _Small Note_ `password_hash()` creates a HASH, a hash is NOT Encryption

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I get that storing is session is not safe, and that is why I am looking for alternatives. But would it be ok to have everybody login to the db with the same MYSQL user (in which case I don't need to store the pw in SESSION)? I am aware of the risks, what are the solutions?

Comment: "would it be ok to have everybody login to the db with the same MYSQL user"...in a web application, yes. You need to re-conceptualise the architecture: It's the **application** which logs into the database, not the user. The **user** logs into the **application**. So you need usernames and passwords for the application, not the database. Those can be stored _in_ the database. Passwords stored in the database should be hashed for security - you can achieve this with PHP's built-in password_hash function (and password_verify for checking a password attempt against the hashed copy).

Comment: (And in that scenario, no passwords need to be stored in the session - once the user has logged into the application, just store their username in the session so you know who's logged in to that session. The database credentials will be fixed, and can be stored safely in a config file on the server somewhere.)

Comment: Thank you ADyson for your accurate answer. I will follow your recommendation. Just a question: what if I use MYSQL users to restrict privileges, and use them as roles (e.g. create 1 account for managers, 1 for developers and so on)? And if not, is there some particular setting to assure enough query calls when everybody is logged with the same mysql account?

Comment: That's not a good approach in a web app. Again, use **one** MySQL account which represents your whole application, not individual users or groups of users. Give it all the SQL rights it needs in order to do all the things which the application needs to do in the database. If you want to have roles, implement that via the **application** users, and write your authorisation rules using application code (e.g. to prevent them from changing certain data or doing certain actions, or whatever, according to your requirements.)